# Adding 1 to each number to subsequent numbers for prioritization list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to add +1 to each number after each subsequent number in a column, starting at the number that I've entered, automatically.

For example:

- I have 20 rows in a column
- I have each row numbered, 1-20
- I decide that #17 (Elderberry) should should be prioritized as #6
- I change the number 17 to the number 6 (Step 1)
- Fruit ranked #6 turns to #7, #7 turns to #8, and so on until #20 (Step 2)**
- All numbers before #6 are unaffected

[Please see example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vafhngJzHML00f4oLKjZLZXbei2kcFJCXwaE6YwhnOI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Some workaround:A1`=row()`  drag fill down to A20; Now move the whole row (17) up and bring it to (6)

Comment: What part of code is giving you grief? Please post some code so that we can see where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

I think this accomplishes what you want.

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()=='Sheet3' && e.range.getColumn()==1 && e.value != e.oldValue)
  {
    var sh=e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var row=e.range.getRow();
    //Logger.log(row);
    var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++)
    {
      if(Number(e.value) > Number(e.oldValue))
      {
        //Logger.log('flag up e.value=%s > e.oldValue=%s',e.value,e.oldValue);//moving up
        if(Number(i+1)!=row && vA[i][0]>e.oldValue && vA[i][0]<=e.value)
        {
          //Logger.log('decr vA[%s][0]=%s',i,vA[i][0]);
          vA[i][0]=vA[i][0]-1;
        }
      }
      if(Number(e.value) < Number(e.oldValue))
      {
        //Logger.log('flag down e.value=%s < e.oldValue=%s',e.value,e.oldValue);//moving down
        if(Number(i+1)!=row && vA[i][0]>=e.value && vA[i][0]<e.oldValue)
        {
          //Logger.log('incr vA[%s][0]=%s',i,vA[i][0]);
          vA[i][0]=vA[i][0]+1;
        }
      }
    }
    sh.getDataRange().setValues(vA);
    var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,vA.length-1,vA[0].length).sort({column:1,ascending:true});
  }
}
```

Here's what my Spreadsheet looked like:

[image]